# multiple lists to rows and columns

Tags: python

I've been looking for answers like panda and the sort, but i dont think i'm allowed to use it, so i'm hitting a wall on my assignment, would appreciate it if anyone can help me. also any suggestions on how to make my code be able to handle string values as inputs, and negative inputs? im very new to python.

```
n = int(input("enter a number:"))
x = range(int(1),n)
list_1 = [x+1 for x in range(n)]
list_1.insert(0,"m")
list_2 = [x+2 for x in range(n)]
list_2.insert(0,"m+1")
list_3 = [(x+1) ** (x+2) for x in range(n)]
list_3.insert(0,"m**(m+1)")
list_of_lists = [list_1, list_2, list_3]

if n>=0:
    for a in zip(*list_of_lists):
        print(*a)


elif n<0:
    print("sorry, only positive integers please")
```

all it gave was

```
m m+1 m**(m+1)
1 2 1
2 3 8
3 4 81
4 5 1024
5 6 15625
```

where I wanted it to be something like

```
m    m+1    m**(m+1)
1    2      1
2    3      8
3    4      81
4    5      1024
5    6      15625
```

Comment: Shouldn't you do the `if n>=0:` check before creating the lists?

Comment: Are you talking about the layout issue?

Comment: @tobias_k yeah you're right hahaha

Comment: @kris yup, but someone helped me already, thanks though. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
n = int(input("enter a number:"))
# Do the check earlier.
if n>=0:
  x = range(int(1),n)
  list_1 = [x+1 for x in range(n)]
  list_1.insert(0,"m")
  list_2 = [x+2 for x in range(n)]
  list_2.insert(0,"m+1")
  list_3 = [(x+1) ** (x+2) for x in range(n)]
  list_3.insert(0,"m**(m+1)")
  list_of_lists = [list_1, list_2, list_3]

  # Print here, use a sep(arator) of \t -> tab
  # instead of the default one which is space.
  for a in zip(*list_of_lists):
        print(*a, sep = '\t', end = '\n')

elif n<0:
    print("sorry, only positive integers please")
```

This prints in console:

```
enter a number: 5
m   m+1 m**(m+1)
1   2   1
2   3   8
3   4   81
4   5   1024
5   6   15625
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
print(*a)
```

use

```
print("{:<8} {:<8} {:<8}".format(*a))
```

It places each element in 8-character width column and left-adjust them (because of `<` in front of 8).